# Does an index speed the calculation of a DATEDIFF of two datetime values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with three columns:

```
id | start_date | end_date
```

I have a view that shows `id` and `DATEDIFF(hour, start_date, end_date)`:

```
id | timespan
```

Will putting an index on the date columns speed that query?  Does this only work with `DATEADD`?  If so, why?  My understanding is that for arithmetic queries like this, a `TABLE SCAN` is required.

Comment: Do you want to speed up queries that use `WHERE view_column = @constant_value` or similar where the `DATEDIFF(hour, start_date, end_date) AS view_column` is in the view definition? I suggest you add the view definition, your queries and the exact version of SQL-Server (2005, 2008, 2008R2, 2012)

Comment: Sounds like something you could test yourself.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO it is, but I was unable to find a source that says this explicitly

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 That says what? That you can test it yourself?

Comment: That says that an index has no benefit for calculations like this because it induces a table scan, rather than a seek.

Comment: You still haven't provided what calculations you need. The `DATEDIFF()` in all the table or a restriction of the table with some conditions.

Comment: the DATEDIFF *is* the table restriction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  It does not.

You can create a computed column and create an index on that:

```
alter table <table> add duration as datediff(hour, start_date, end_date);

create index on <table>(duration);
```

Of course, the index will be most useful if `duration` is used in `where` clause, an `on` clause, or `order by`.

Comment: Okay.  I thought the guy telling me that an index would speed things up was a dumbass.  He asked how to speed up this view, and I suggested a calculated column.  He said an index would be better.  Thanks for confirming my thoughts

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 You may want to edit your comment for language before it gets flagged.